# Votes cast: month, week

Tags: support, design

The *Votes Cast* section on the user-profile activity page, has *Month* and *Week* fields. What do these indicate?

[image: votes cast section]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This indicates how many votes you have cast this month and this week.

Why the number of votes for a month smaller than the number of votes for the week?  That's because the month is 2 days old and the week is 4 days old, at the moment of writing.

Comment: It’s so obvious now. Can’t believe I didn’t recognize that. Thanks.